# At the event of Jesus' last Passover, did Jesus bless/thank God or the bread?

Tags: jesus

Matthew 26:26-27 KJV

> <sup>**25**</sup> And as they were eating, Jesus took bread, and blessed *it*, and brake *it*, and gave *it* to the disciples, and said, Take, eat; this is my body. <sup>**26**</sup> And he took the cup, and gave thanks, and gave *it* to them, saying, Drink ye all of it;

YLT

> <sup>**25**</sup> And while they were eating, Jesus having taken the bread, and having blessed, did brake, and was giving to the disciples, and said, 'Take, eat, this is my body;' <sup>**26**</sup> and having taken the cup, and having given thanks, he gave to them, saying, 'Drink ye of it -- all;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us examine the two verses separately as two different verbs are involved.  I will use my own translation in both cases.

**Matt 26:26** - Now, [as] they were eating, Jesus having taken **bread**, and having bless [**it**], broke [**it**], and having given [**it**] to the disciples, He said, "Take [**it**], eat [**it**]; this is my body."

Notice that the implied "it" is always the bread, first mentioned in the accusative, becomes the implied object of the subsequent verbs: blessed, broke, given.

**Matt 26:27** - And having taken a **cup** and having given thanks [for **it**], He gave [**it**] to them, saying "Drink from it all [of you]."

Again, the implied "it" is the cup which again becomes the implied accusative object of the subsequent verbs: given thanks, gave, drink - the final one being explicit.  Note that "to them" is a secondary object because it is in the dative case.  "Cup" is also accusative, but only needs to mention once to become the implied object of the subsequent verbs.

Conclusion: Jesus blessed the bread and gave thanks for the cup (actually, its contents).